# Importing huge SQL file into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that is about 20 GB in size. I generated script for DB and content and now trying to import to different server. I googled and found such thing:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -i C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\SQL_backup.sql
```

While executing `sqlcmd` like this, the process starts but after some time I get an error :

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Server WIN-I79PRE6OQTV, Line 793
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '
>         
>           172551665 ......

So my question is - if I have generated script using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - why do I get such an error while importing the data?

How can I resolve this issue?

P.S the column that this error complains contains XML data stored as string and is very long string.

Is there any other backup/ restore way?

**UPDATED**

I ran - > dbcc checkdb('CreditInfoDB',REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)

and this is the result

```
DBCC results for 'CreditInfoDB'.
Service Broker Msg 9675, State 1: Message Types analyzed: 14.
Service Broker Msg 9676, State 1: Service Contracts analyzed: 6.
Service Broker Msg 9667, State 1: Services analyzed: 3.
Service Broker Msg 9668, State 1: Service Queues analyzed: 3.
Service Broker Msg 9669, State 1: Conversation Endpoints analyzed: 0.
Service Broker Msg 9674, State 1: Conversation Groups analyzed: 0.
Service Broker Msg 9670, State 1: Remote Service Bindings analyzed: 0.
Service Broker Msg 9605, State 1: Conversation Priorities analyzed: 0.
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrscols'.
There are 1092 rows in 14 pages for object "sys.sysrscols".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrowsets'.
There are 147 rows in 3 pages for object "sys.sysrowsets".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysclones'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysclones".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysallocunits'.
There are 172 rows in 2 pages for object "sys.sysallocunits".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysfiles1'.
There are 2 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysfiles1".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysseobjvalues'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysseobjvalues".
DBCC results for 'sys.syspriorities'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syspriorities".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysdbfrag'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysdbfrag".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysfgfrag'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysfgfrag".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysdbfiles'.
There are 2 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysdbfiles".
DBCC results for 'sys.syspru'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syspru".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysbrickfiles'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysbrickfiles".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysphfg'.
There are 1 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysphfg".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysprufiles'.
There are 2 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysprufiles".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysftinds'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysftinds".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysowners'.
There are 14 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysowners".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysdbreg'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysdbreg".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysprivs'.
There are 141 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysprivs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysschobjs'.
There are 2271 rows in 52 pages for object "sys.sysschobjs".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscsrowgroups'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syscsrowgroups".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysexttables'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysexttables".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscolpars'.
There are 890 rows in 14 pages for object "sys.syscolpars".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxlgns'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysxlgns".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxsrvs'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysxsrvs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysnsobjs'.
There are 1 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysnsobjs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysusermsgs'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysusermsgs".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscerts'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syscerts".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrmtlgns'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysrmtlgns".
DBCC results for 'sys.syslnklgns'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syslnklgns".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxprops'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysxprops".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysscalartypes'.
There are 34 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysscalartypes".
DBCC results for 'sys.systypedsubobjs'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.systypedsubobjs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysidxstats'.
There are 227 rows in 4 pages for object "sys.sysidxstats".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysiscols'.
There are 419 rows in 2 pages for object "sys.sysiscols".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysendpts'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysendpts".
DBCC results for 'sys.syswebmethods'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syswebmethods".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysbinobjs'.
There are 23 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysbinobjs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysaudacts'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysaudacts".

DBCC results for 'sys.sysobjvalues'.
There are 234 rows in 22 pages for object "sys.sysobjvalues".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscscolsegments'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syscscolsegments".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscsdictionaries'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syscsdictionaries".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysclsobjs'.
There are 16 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysclsobjs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrowsetrefs'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysrowsetrefs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysremsvcbinds'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysremsvcbinds".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxmitqueue'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysxmitqueue".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrts'.

There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syscommittab".
DBCC results for 'sys.filetable_updates_2105058535'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.filetable_updates_2105058535".
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database     'CreditInfoDB'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, and should, use ETL to backup to a file and import it to the new server. ETL is going to be way more effective than scripts for large data sets.

Microsoft provides SSIS to do this exact thing.  You can export to a RAW file (don't go via CSV or XLSX option), and import it into the other server.

Comment: what is ELT? is it some tool software?

Comment: I run : dbcc checkdb('CreditInfoDB',REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)

Answer (score 0):

More likely your script file is being truncated at some point in the process. The parser have a file size limit (you are using multiple processes [create, load, execute, etc.]).

The best way to perform such task would be a database backup/restore.
[image: Create backup in SSMS context menu]

Edit: Based on comment from OP, added information.

If the data is corrupted then it makes no difference what approach you take. And as far as wanting a new database, well; the idea is to restore as a New Database, not to override the old one.

Before taking the backup run an integrity check on the source database. After the backup; verify your backup media.

[image: Restore backup in SSMS dialog]

Comment: I had a problem with hard drive and now database queries are very slow or result in errors. That's why I wanted to create new database from script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase packet size and see if the error is gone or another error comes up?

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -a 32767 -i C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\SQL_backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of running backup/restore you could also try just moving the database as is by either detaching the database and then reattaching it in it's new location or using the move database.

Both methods are covered on msdn [Detach MsSQL database 2008 - 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187858.aspx) and [Move MsSQL database 2008 - 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms345483%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) (I wouldn't normally post links but this is direct from the official support site so should stand up for a few years)